# Determining CausalImpact when there are 0s in the response variable

Tags: r, time-series

I am trying to run CausalImpact to look at the impact of an advertising campaign on customers who have shopped in a long time at the merchant in question.

One of the variables I am using as a predictor is that population's shopping behavior at other merchants during that same time period.

By definition, there will be little correlation between the two, but general shopping behavior will impact specific merchant sales.

My question is: How does CausalImpact, built with advertising campaigns in mind, deal with "New" customers, who basically have many 0 values over time in the pre-period?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> By definition, there will be little correlation between the [incidence of shopping a long time at one vendor and the incidence of shopping a long time at another vendor]

Are you perhaps conflating the idea of having "little correlation" with having negative correlation?

If having "shopped a long time at a vendor" is an eligibility criterion for the participants in your sample, then new customers are ineligible. You have to subset them. Once they shop a long time (and leave), then they are eligible to come back and shop a long time again.